# Proportionally resize width and height of div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Couple of days I am trying to make a div re-size like an image(proportionally).

For example If I have a div with dimensions 500x140, I want it on a browser re-size to react like an image that has width="100%".
I find out a similar questions but they didn't work for me.

Is there a way to do that(without using a dummy image)?

**EDIT:**
[image]

p.s. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14631825/189937

Comment: I use an approach like this guy does here for my sticky footers. When you have a container div you are able to manipulate inner divs much easier than you could before hand. This is bc you give the div a position:relative. I think you may want to use the inline-block yourself. http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

**HTM:**

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
        something...
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width:1280px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
}
.parent:before {
    margin-top: 25%;
    content: '.';
    font-size: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The interesting part in the code is the margin-top of the .parent:before selector. By this you can adjust the basic height of the div.
**Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ndzCL/**

It is not the perfect solution but it is simple and use only CSS.

Thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the dimensions as a pixel number, try setting it to a percentage.
You may set a min-width and min-height as well

Comment: Ok, but how to keep the proportions on re-size(based on the width of the browser)?

Comment: I understand what you mean. Perhaps this link will give you some insight. http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `max-height` and `max-width`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AA4KX/1/)

```
div{
    max-height:100vh; /* or 100% */
    max-width:100vw;  /* or 100% */
}
```

`100vh` means 100% of view port height and `100vw` means 100% of view port width.

you can use percentage too. percentage take parent width. for example if you set `max-width:50%` for an element, it takes 50% of parent's width (same for height).

**update:**

you can use media query too, like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  div {
    /* some style */
  }
}
```

this code work when `max-width` be equal to `500px`. [**here is DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AA4KX/2/)

Comment: This is not working; ah, people...why you don't understand that I want the div to resize proportionally...Maybe I have to add an example image in the question...

Comment: I dont't want to use media query because the resize will not be fluid...I will update my question